# Не работает вывод категорий Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
    public function showListPage(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::with('category', 'images')
        ->where(function($q) use($request) {
            if ($request->has($request->category_url)) {
                $q->where('category_url', '=', (string)$request->category_url);
            }
        })
        ->whereIsActive(true)
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->paginate(self::POSTS_PER_PAGE);

    $category = category::all();

    return view('post.home', ['posts' => $posts, 'category' => $category]);
}
```

Выводит всегда все новости.

```
Route::get('/novosti', ['uses' => 'PostController@showListPage']); тут всё норм.
Route::get('/novosti/{category_url}', ['uses' => 'PostController@showListPage']);
```

Comment: какая ошибка? что в `$posts` лежит после запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('/novosti', ['uses' => 'PostController@showListPage']);
Route::get('/novosti/{category_url}', ['uses' => 'PostController@showListPage']);

    public function showListPage($categoryUrl = null)
{
    $category = Category::whereCategoryUrl($categoryUrl)->first();

    $posts = Post::with('category', 'images')
        ->where(function($q) use($category) {
            if ($category && $category->category_id) {
                $q->whereCategoryId($category->category_id);
            }
        })
        ->whereIsActive(true)
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->paginate(self::POSTS_PER_PAGE);

    $category = Category::all();

    return view('post.home', ['posts' => $posts, 'category' => $category]);
}
```

Comment: за запросы в роутах, нужно очень очень больно бить по рукам

Comment: Я плохо разбираюсь. А что в них плохого?

Comment: Запомните писать запросы в роутах - это очень плохой тон. запросы принято писать в контролерах.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте следующим образом.

1) Так как вы используете один и тот же метод в контроллере для всех новостей и для категорий, используйте один маршрут с необязательным параметром

```
Route::get('/novosti/{category_url?}', ['uses' => 'PostController@showListPage']);
```

2) Для чего Вам в контроллере весь `Request`? пускай в контроллер передается только нужные параметры из запроса, т.е ваша категрия

```
public function showListPage($category_url = null)
```

По умолчанию мы присваиваем NULL, это нужно для того, что если запрос был без категории.

3) В Вашем запросе не работает условие `$request->has`, т.к оно предназначено для работы с формами.

```
$posts = Post::with('category', 'images')
        ->where(function($q) use($category_url) {
            if ($category_url) {
                $q->where('category_url', '=', (string)$category_url);
            }
        })
        ->whereIsActive(true)
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->paginate(self::POSTS_PER_PAGE);
```